# Filter domains from google search without -site:example.com?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

Is there a way I can block sites from my google searches? For instance, if I have a tech question often one of the first results that comes up will be to a site that wastes my time with wanting me to click here, click there, register this, get points, spend money, then finally get to see a bad answer. I'd rather just not have this site show up in my results any more.

Any way I can do this?

**Update**

Google just released this, which does what I was asking for.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef

Comment: You didn't mention you were using Chrome. You should make your update a separate answer and "accept" it.

Comment: The question's not about chrome, I asked this months ago and updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `-site:` syntax would be the best way.

Any other approach (editing hosts files, proxies etc.) will still mean that Google will return a link to the site, but you won't be able to click it.

I've been caught out by this myself and I read the URLs more closely now.